# Uploading a file to Google Cloud Storage with Node.js ('bucketName' has already been declared)

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, aws-lambda, google-cloud-storage

I am having my first play with [Google Cloud Storage](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/blob/master/samples/files.js) from within AWS Lambda and also locally on my laptop. I have the Environment Variables set in Lambda using

GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS

However, when I try and upload the demo.txt file within the zip I get

`'bucketName' has already been declared`

I have created the bucket in Google Cloud and also Enabled the API. Can anyone help fix the code? (mostly taken from Google Cloud docs anyway)

```
async function uploadFile(bucketName, filename) {
  // [START storage_upload_file]
  // Imports the Google Cloud client library
  const { Storage } = require('@google-cloud/storage');

  // Your Google Cloud Platform project ID
  const projectId = 'apple-ration-27434';

  // Creates a client
  const storage = new Storage();

  var bucketName = 'mybucket-saturday';
  var filename = 'demo.txt';

  // Uploads a local file to the bucket
  await storage.bucket(bucketName).upload(filename, {
    // Support for HTTP requests made with `Accept-Encoding: gzip`
    gzip: true,
    metadata: {
      // Enable long-lived HTTP caching headers
      // Use only if the contents of the file will never change
      // (If the contents will change, use cacheControl: 'no-cache')
      cacheControl: 'public, max-age=31536000',
    },
  });

  console.log(`${filename} uploaded to ${bucketName}.`);
  // [END storage_upload_file]
}
```

Comment: @Dan Cornilescu, can you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74081978/error-creating-gcs-signed-post-policy-for-uploading-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a conflict for `bucketName`:

- you're getting it as argument to `uploadFile`:

  ```
  async function uploadFile(bucketName, filename) {
  ```
- you're also declaring it locally inside `uploadFile`:

  ```
  const bucketName = 'mynewbucket-saturday';
  ```

You need to pick only one method of specifying the bucket name and drop the other.

Comment: Thanks Dan, I have got the AWS Lambda function working using your comments but when I try and run it locally as per the Google docs in the link it doesn't work. https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/blob/master/samples/files.js

Comment: You should ask a separate question. But be specific, "doesn't work" isn't useful. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.